# Laravel stop events propagation

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have registered two **queued** event handlers on an event :

```
// in app/Providers/EventServiceProvider.php
//...

'App\Events\UserWasCreated' => [
    'App\Handlers\Events\RegisterInSalesForce',
    'App\Handlers\Events\SendMailToAdmin',
],
```

I want to run `SendMailToAdmin` only if `RegisterInSalesForce` is OK. I tried to return `false` in `RegisterInSalesForce` on failure and `true` on success but it does not work.

What should I do ? Did I miss something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do it exactly like that, but you can do a workaround for that:

in your `RegisterInSalesForce` event, you can fire another event (such as `RegisteredInSales`) and then listen to it.

```
class RegisterInSalesForce {

    public function handle()
    {
        // do your stuff

        if($stuff == true){
            $response = Event::fire(new RegisteredInSales);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a separate Event handler and add the logic to a method or else have another event "RegisteredInSalesForce" so a listener to it will dispatch the command "SendMailToAdmin".

Comment: Thanks, your answer is OK too ! (I can accept only one)

Answer (score 1):

In Laravel 5.5 you can just return `false` to stop propagation of an event.

From Laravel 5.5 documentation

**Stopping The Propagation Of An Event**

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/events#defining-listeners

> Sometimes, you may wish to stop the propagation of an event to other listeners. You may do so by returning `false` from your listener's handle method.